# What is the difference between ADTs and ASDLs?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, type-checking, abstract-data-types, domain-specific-languages

ASDL stands for Abstract Syntax Description Language (ASDL), whereby ADT stands for Algebraic data type.

By looking at [Python.asdl](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Parser/Python.asdl) it appears to me to be the same thingy, just with different names, which I highly assume is wrong.

Can anyone explain what the difference is?

Comment: I will not write an answer. Instead, here are two articles worthy of reading, [What is Zephyr ASDL?](https://www.oilshell.org/blog/2016/12/11.html) and [Design of CPython’s Compiler](https://devguide.python.org/compiler/). Of course, we also have the [the technical report on the Zephyr Abstract Syntax Description Language](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/research/techreps/TR-554-97) and [the Wikipedia entry on Algebraic Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).